# how to use/read this curl api and add limit for data, POST method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-native, rest

so i got this api from my partner and i never use this kind of api format and i asked to put limit parameter so it will only recieve certain data limit. But i don't understand where to put this  `--data`.
if the method is GET it's fine i just need to add `?limit=10&page=1` in the url but for the POST method how ? i usually put `body:{"limit":10}` for POST but now it doesn't work

```
  curl --request POST \
  --url https://base-url.com/api/v2/order/all/79025884 \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --cookie 'connect.sid=s%253ArO7T68J_dUxbwAoogHU.ezS9SwNk1gb8AgJxOUqjzoJoza9ETpE7t1TDugussQY; token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJwaG9uZU51bWJlciI6IjA4MTExNzA5MjIxIiwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJGbG8iLCJpYXQiOjE2NjE2NDI0NjcsImV4cCI62N30.8hyXmK3H0N9Iccedv9XSs6_rbtmToS8B0woxWNj9IXM' \
  --data '{
    "limit":10,
    "page":1
}'
```

my fetch api code

```
  const url = APIConfig.SERVER.ORDER + "/all/" + userID;
    fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "content-type": "application/JSON" },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setOrderList(data.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like :

```
const url = APIConfig.SERVER.ORDER + "/all/" + userID;
    fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "content-type": "application/JSON" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
                limit:10,
                  page:1
             })
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setOrderList(data.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      });
```

Hope it helps, feel free for doubts